# android studio using IBM MobileFirstPlatform 8.0 has a error : didn't find class okhttp3.internal.JavaNetCookieJar

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

the error info:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.wl.android, PID: 2774
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/internal/JavaNetCookieJar;
    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.<init>(HttpClientManager.java:103)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.createInstance(HttpClientManager.java:227)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createInstance(WLClient.java:179)
    at com.wl.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "**okhttp3.internal.JavaNetCookieJar**" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wl.android-1/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.wl.android-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.<init>(HttpClientManager.java:103) 
    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.createInstance(HttpClientManager.java:227) 
    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createInstance(WLClient.java:179) 
    at com.wl.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

from this message ,maybe i using a incorrect okhttp3 version, but i don't how to do, please tell me that what is correct version of oktttp3 jar file i can use, thank you very much.

Comment: post your build.gradle at app level please

Comment: gradle-3.3-all
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wl.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
}

Comment: Edit your question and post your gradle code in it

Comment: What `repositories` have you defined in your build.gradle ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your IBM Mobile First platform dependency in the build.gradle to

```
compile(name: 'ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation:8.0.2017040512', ext: 'aar')
```

As per the documentation [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/04/06/8-0-ifix-release/) this is the latest certified version for 8.0. This should solve your problem.

As a best practice it is good to provide specific version numbers to ensure that you do not run into surprises. Using dynamic version can always be a problem. More on this here http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/.

Comment: [I by visiting the link to solve the problem.](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/android/#adding-the-mobilefirst-native-sdk)

Comment: I don't see the relevance with your issue and the link you pointed to. However can you provide your repository details on how you managed to run into the error reported? It would be great if you could share the project recreating the same problem.

Comment: Configure three places in the file build.gradle(module level):  
under ‘apply plugin’ add:  
    repositories{  
        jcenter()  
    }  
in 'Android' add:  
    packagingOptions {  
        pickFirst 'META-INF/ASL2.0'  
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'  
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'  
    }  
in 'dependencies' add  
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.foundation:ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation:8.0.+'

Comment: This is after you fixed the issue. I wanted the changes before you could fix the problem. Wonder why the application complained of okhttp3 when the library actually uses okhttp.

Comment: if directly using okhttp3 jar,  it would be has a runtime exception : class no found okhttp3.internal.JavaNetCookieJar , i try to find it the all releases of okhttp3 ,but i can not found this class, i think the IBM MobileFirst may be use source code and encapsulate it, so direct configuration okhttp3 in gradle.build will be get a exception.